# Driving load with sine wave from signal generator

Tags: amplifier, signal, inverter, generator, sine

I would like to use a signal generator to generate a sine wave. This sine wave will then need to drive an inductor as part of a transformer. What is the most efficient way to give this signal greater power ability through a MOSFET or BJT amplifier? Currents will be quite small < 1A but the signal generator can not deliver to the load.

Comment: Can't you imagine that telling something about the frequency would not be completely irrelevant? 50Hz? 3kHz? 30 kHz? 300kHz? 3MHz? 30MHz? 300MHz? 3GHz? ...

Comment: Also specify the load impedance and the required voltage.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to get a signal generator to supply your 1A load.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok I am trying to use a 5V DC supply to drive a transformer. Can use a signal generator to generate the sinusoid but can't use it for a power supply. Maximum power is 0.25W so current would be far lower. Transformer is just winding wire so resistance would be low. Frequency ~ 10kHz.

Comment: Esssentially an inverter without need for sinusoid generation.

Comment: "I am trying to use a 5V DC supply to drive a transformer" - for what purpose?

Comment: The transformer will then drive some load and the only goal is to maximize power delivery and efficiency.

Comment: XY problem. Don't offer-up half-baked solutions to under specified requirements and expect a sensible answer.

Comment: How do you drive a transformer with DC?

Comment: Since 10KHz is in the audio range, you actually have a good shot with audio amplifiers. If you build something yourself, you would end up re-inventing audio amplifiers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For a bench-top 1-10 Mhz 10 V signal general, if you aren't too concerned with amplitude accuracy and distortion, you can go for a class-ab buffer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjqmCG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The challenge with a discrete class-ab stage is R1/R2 are there firstly to account for errors in thermal tracking between Q4-Q1 and Q2-Q3, as to not send your output stage into thermal runaway. Secondly they are used for SOA protection (not included) to sense output current.

Edit: Power Amplifier

It is much easier to just buy a power opamp such as the [OPA541](http://www.ti.com/product/OPA541/datasheet)

Comment: That's not what comes first to mind when someone says *"classic buffer"* in this context.  The more normal classic buffer would probably be better here.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop Agreed labeling it 'classic' is pushing it

Comment: Of course you can always add an op-amp and go for a power amplifier too...

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit about adding the opamp for a power amplifier?